# How can I use conditional formatting to apply different fill color for products?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to find a way to apply different fill color for products according to produc type. Thank you for your help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SlazSLC5d6vUTGxnZTwgLrNUh_B2k1h__GqjH0ol9W4/edit?usp=sharing

My desired result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Conditional formatting** under **Format** menu and using the custom formula:

```
=C1="BM"
```

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

and do it for each color and product type you need.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

- If the product type is in different sheet **Type**

#### Changes:

Apply to range: **B2:B1000**

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, INDIRECT("Type!A2:B"), 2, 0)="BM"
=VLOOKUP(B2, INDIRECT("Type!A2:B"), 2, 0)="JZ"
=VLOOKUP(B2, INDIRECT("Type!A2:B"), 2, 0)="PM"
=VLOOKUP(B2, INDIRECT("Type!A2:B"), 2, 0)="SD"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.   I have one more question.   What if my product type is in different sheet ?   Can I still use this formula ?     please check my sheet link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SlazSLC5d6vUTGxnZTwgLrNUh_B2k1h__GqjH0ol9W4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @zongshita, That should be doable. I edited my post to show you the changes needed to be done. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thank you. I clicked the accept button.